# What is the purpose of gradle's buildSrc folder?

Tags: configuration, structure, gradle

In gradle, what is the purpose of using a `buildSrc` file as a top level, as opposed to just a typical java project layout (src/main/java)?

If I have a layout of

```
src
   main
      java
```

or

```
buildSrc
    src
       main
          java
```

What would be the difference (or the reason for doing this)? Is it more useful in multi module projects? Even for a multi module project, couldn't I do something like

```
proj1
  src


proj2
  src
```

And then just have a top level build.gradle (at the same level as `proj1` and `proj2`) that defines common settings across the projects?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

`buildSrc` is a separate *build* whose purpose is to build any tasks, plugins, or other classes which are intended to be used in *build scripts* of the main build, but don't have to be shared across builds.(*) It wouldn't be possible to build such classes as part of the main build, because they have to exist before the main build's build scripts can even be compiled/evaluated, and Gradle compiles/evaluates all build scripts before it does any work (configuration vs. execution phase).

Compared to putting all build code into build scripts, `buildSrc` gives you a way to develop build code more like regular code, as classes that you can test, import into your IDE, etc. It is one way to keep build scripts simple and DRY even for more complicated builds.

`buildSrc` is more often seen in multi-project builds simply because larger builds are more likely to implement their own custom tasks and plugins.

Over time, `buildSrc` will grow into a more general capability of executing multiple dependent *builds* in a single Gradle invocation.

(*) Sharing classes across builds is possible but more involved. In particular, you'll need to publish the classes to a repository, and consuming builds have to explicitly import them from there, similar to when sharing production libraries between builds.

Answer (score 11):

> In gradle, what is the purpose of using a buildSrc file as a top
> level, as opposed to just a typical java project layout
> (src/main/java)?

You can definitely do this. It is known as a [composite build](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/composite_builds.html) in gradle, but you have to tell Gradle to [**include**](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/composite_builds.html#composite_build_intro) any builds from that folder. A [unique property](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/organizing_gradle_projects.html#sec:build_sources) of a top-level `buildSrc` folder is that gradle automatically treats it as an included build.

*Note that even though `buildSrc` is treated as a composite build, it is not visible in the list of included builds when you run [`gradle.getIncludedBuilds()`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/invocation/Gradle.html#getIncludedBuilds--)*. I believe the reason is because the list is reserved for builds which you manually included in your [`settings.gradle`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.initialization.Settings.html).

For you to also include `src/main/java` as a composite build, you have to run your gradle script using the `--include-build` flag, followed by the path to `src/main/java`. This is an unusual place for an included build, but gradle won't complain.

> And then just have a top level build.gradle (at the same level as
> proj1 and proj2) that defines common settings across the projects?

You CAN have a top-level `build.gradle` at the same level as your `proj1`, and `proj2` sub-projects. This is typically how most multi-project projects are structured.

---

As [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13875350/2089675) already highlighted, the purpose of the `buildSrc` project is to create custom plugins or tasks *which is meant to be shared locally* among the different projects in your build. **This is not to imply that you cannot create those custom tasks and plugins in your top-level `build.gradle`**. You can do it this way, but the problem is that you will not be able to use it in any of your sub-projects.

*Remember that being able to import something in java/groovy requires that thing to exist in a proper java/groovy file (or module for java 9+). Seeing as your `build.gradle` is simply a script, it is not arbitrary to simply import a plugin or task from it.*

As I have already pointed out and this is from the [Gradle docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/organizing_gradle_projects.html#sec:build_sources), one of the reasons for having a `buildSrc` directory is:

> Upon discovery of the directory, Gradle automatically compiles and
> tests this code and **puts it in the classpath of your build script**.

As you can see, the `buildSrc` acts as an extension of your build process in that it can add additional functionality to all your project's build scripts.

---

A few more points:

- Any `dependencies` declared in your `buildSrc/build.gradle` is visible to the rest of the build scripts in your project.
- The `buildscript` block in your `buildSrc/build.gradle` is only visible to `buildSrc/build.gradle` and nothing else.
- Any plugin class defined in `buildSrc` [can be used](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_plugins.html#sec:packaging_a_plugin) in any build script in your project, and does not need to be declared in a `META-INF/gradle-plugins`.
- Any dependencies defined in your main `build.gradle` or any of your subprojects is not visible in `buildSrc`. If you remember that this folder is treated as an included build (i.e. external), it should make sense why it cannot see the classpath of the project that includes it.

Comment: Another helpful fact: when importing classes from `buildSrc` into a build file, note that imports are resolved __after__ the `buildscript` section. This means that you cannot use imported classes in the `buildscript` section. You can, however, use them via fully qualified names.