# Link gradle subproject to task

Tags: java, gradle

This is how my project is set up

```
root
- settings.gradle
- build.gradle
- subp1
- subp2
```

*settings.gradle:*

```
rootProject.name = 'subs'
include subp1, subp2
```

*build.gradle:*

```
....
subprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    task dev(type: org.gradle.api.DefaultTask) //OK!
    task subdev(type: subp1.GenerateTask) //!!NOT OK!
}
```

*subp1/src/main/java/subp1/GenerateTask.java:*

```
package subp1;

import org.gradle.api.DefaultTask;
import org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskAction;


public class GenerateTask extends DefaultTask {

    @TaskAction
    public void generate() {
            System.out.println("subp1");
        }

}
```

It looks like subp1.GenerateTask is not available when I am building the task in build.gradle.

How do I let gradle know this task is available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That won't work.

You've placed your task in a place that Gradle is supposed to build. It means, that when Gradle reads your `GenerateTask` it will be already started with some classes on a classpath and your `GenerateTask` won't be there as it is not yet compiled.

What you have to do for Gradle to see your task is to put it in [`buildSrc`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/organizing_gradle_projects.html#sec:build_sources). I would also suggest your to read this [perfect answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13875350/750510).