# In gradle 7.x, is it possible to invoke function defined in `org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.*` in buildSrc?

Tags: gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl, buildsrc

In my multi-module project built by Gradle, a few repeated dependency declarations can be aggregated into a utility function

The easiest way to define such function that can be used by all submodules is to do it in buildSrc:

[What is the purpose of gradle's buildSrc folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13874680/what-is-the-purpose-of-gradles-buildsrc-folder)

Unfortunately, its classpath resolving seems to be broken. If I import any function from the kotlin-dsl module:

```
import org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.`implementation`
```

I got the following error:

```
e: /home/peng/git/shapesafe/buildSrc/src/main/kotlin/init.kt: (5, 30): Unresolved reference: `implementation`
```

How could this happen?

Answer (score 0):

This means, that you have imported nothing at all:

> Unresolved reference: `implementation`

You'd probably would have to import some more:

```
import org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.apply
import org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.dependencies
import org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.kotlin
import org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.*
```

... where `*` also includes `implementation`.

Comment: why would I have imported nothing? this is a legitimate path

Comment: @tribbloid The error message tells the opposite; "unresolved reference" means that the import did not happen, maybe due to the back-ticks used, where I'd not be too certain, that they're legitimate syntax. Have you tried to replace that broken import with the one's suggested?